# What is the ruby on rails equivalent for $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ldap

In PHP, we can use `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` to get the password entered by the user from apache basic authentication.

How do we go by doing this in Rails?

EDIT: `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is equivalent to `request.env['REMOTE_USER']`.

Comment: maybe this? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-authorization

Answer (score 0):

What eventually did it for me is this:

```rb
require 'base64'

user_pass = Base64.decode64(request.authorization.split(' ')[1])
username = user_pass.split(':')[0]
password = user_pass.split(':')[1]
```